# API-s for songs and movies

Tags: api, rest

I've googled the google out of google, does anyone have any good suggestions for random movie and -song API's? Not looking for anything special, I just need something to return a simple title. The simplest things seem to be hard to find.

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want to get from the api. but for example a quick google search showed this open source database + API for music: https://www.programmableweb.com/api/discogs and for movies it looks like Utelly might be helpful but haven't looked at anything for long or in-depth. https://rapidapi.com/utelly/api/utelly/

Answer (score 7):

Previously, I made a movie app on android and used data parsing API. I'm using The Movie DB, but you have to register an account first to get the API key from the website.
Sign up here:
https://www.themoviedb.org/signup
You can follow the directions from The Movie DB website to get your API Key:
https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction